# Rendering ol.style.Text as HTML in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to display some text in my feature using the vector style settings.
I am doing as follow:

```
new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      offsetY: -10,
      font: '18px Calibri,sans-serif',
      text: feature.get('label'),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ec971f'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 3
      })
    })
});
```

in order to display a label on my map. The problem is that the html is rendered as text.
for example: 10km<sup>2</sup> is rendered as 10km<sup>2</sup>

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can get rid of the tags by adding the HTML string to a dummy element, then calling its `innerText` property, however I don't think it's possible to convert tags to their representatives in JavaScript. Example for the quasi-solution: https://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/fecbx6cm/

Comment: Well, nice propostion Gabor, but I was hoping of a solution without plumbing :P Thank you anyway, I might go with that solution !

Comment: Updated the fiddle to add minimal, but compatible superscript conversion support.